# Ajax first time try

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

Could you please help me? 
I'm trying Ajax for the first time? what I'm missing?

Ajax code (It gets to the confirm dialog, then nothing happens).

```
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script>
          //anyjscode

          jQuery(document).ready(function() 
          {

            jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e) 
            {

              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajaxSetup(
              {
                headers: 
                {
                 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
              });

              confirm ('¿very sure?');

              jQuery.ajax(
              {
                url: "{{ url('/gymmgr/public/notas/test/') }}",
                method:'get',
                data:
                {
                  dcmTest:jQuery('#dcmTest').val()
                },
                sucess: function(result)
                {
                  console.log(result);
                }
              });


            } );    
          } );    

        </script>
```

This is the route at my web.php file

```
    Route::get('notas/test/', 'NotasController@test')->name('notas.test');
```

And it's code

```
public function test()
{
    dd('Test');
}
```

Part of the code I'm using for the test, this at my view.

```
                                <div>
                                  <label for="dcmTest">Test</label>
                                  <input type="number" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    min="0.00" 
                                    max="100000.00" 
                                    step="0.01" 
                                    name="dcmTest" 
                                    id="dcmTest" 
                                    placeholder="test" 
                                    value=0 
                                    readonly>
                                </div>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ajaxSubmit">OK</button>
                              </div>
```

This is what i got after the call at my console. Could you help me to interpret it? did it really load? why the dd function wasn't call at all?

[image]

Does it mean it arrived? why it doesn't showed the text? it's at client side...

[image]

Comment: _"It gets to the confirm dialog, then nothing happens"_, you haven't told it to do anything except log the ajaxed data to the console, hit F12 and click on the console tab you should see a log message there. `ajax()` doesn't automatically load the result into the page. Also you have a typo: `sucess: function(result)` it is `success`

Comment: You have over complicated this very simple use case. Well, more directly, you've allowed jQuery to overcomplicate this simple use case. Please investigate the use of `fetch`. This will provide a modern view of accomplishing your goal. Nice examples can be found here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: should'n it call the test function and stop showing the "test" text?

Comment: Yes, and it probably is. The output of that PHP function will be the response to the AJAX request. This should be logged to your browser console (see first comment above) via your `console.log(result)` line

Comment: Ok, I post the calling at console...

Comment: Note your backtend `test()` function is being called hence why the Preview area of the Network tab is showing the `"Test"` string.  Also note the Console tab to the left of the Network tab is where you would have seen the console.log() of your result

Comment: "Test" is shown because you `dd("Test")`. If you want to output the data that you send in the ajax request, you can use `return response()->json(['data' => $request->dcmTest]);`

Comment: Ok, but it's not showing at my navigator window, but only the console...